# Full Cluster vs Load Balancing

Tags: .net, asp.net, load-balancing

Is there any solutions that "increases power of a single machine" instead of traffic distribution between different hosts.

I mean the following schema:

"Central server" receives all requests and for its execution it provide "a copy of shared memory" to different hosts.

Thanks a lot.

P.S. I need that for .NET based web application.

Comment: This would seem more appropriate on ServerFault.

Comment: khm,... probably... ok. Will go there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualization allows you to get greater utilization out of a single physical host.

Also, threading and asynchronous models are common mechanisms to to increase efficiency/performance.

EDIT: based on your comment below, what you're looking for is a server fabric.

DISCLAIMER: I work for Apprenda. We have a product called SaaSGrid. It is, among other things, a .NET server fabric. http://www.saasgrid.com

There aren't a lot of server fabric infrastructures out there -- most of them belong to big companies with cloud offerings. Also, not to be confused with Azure AppFabric, Microsoft has a collection of technologies under the heading Windows Server AppFabric that may enable you to build this yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849

Comment: Virtualization means few different processes on one machine... but I would like to have one I would say "main process" that consumes resources of other CPU(s) located on other machines...